# How to position a shape in a chart?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to position a shape in a chart in Excel through VBA.

I set the parameters of the position. The result is the shape in a slightly different position.

I have searched the Internet but I have not found a satisfying answer as to why this happens.

I use this code

```
Set shpRect = Chart1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 75, 250, 175)
```

It generates a rectangle not in the 50, 75 position but in the position 60, 80.

Comment: How do you establish that the `Top` and `Left` is 80 and 60? Your code works for me and if I get the `Top` and `Left` properties they are 75 and 50.

Comment: I have a chart that has a numbered x axis and while the left position of the shape should be between 0 and 1, it is greater than one meaning that the position is wrong as it should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: So you want to do this command - `AddShape` - but give parameters that are actually relative to the axes of the chart ?

Comment: yes. but I give it parameters relative to chart e.g. left between 0 and 1 I calculate the value I see it and it is correct and I give the command and it prints it after value 1

Answer (score 0):

What about positioning the Shape to a certain cell, let's say "C3", after it's created:

```
Set shpRect = Chart1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 75, 250, 175)

With shpRect '<-- modify the shape's position 
    .Top = Range("C3").Top
    .Left = Range("C3").Left
End With
```

Comment: Thank you but the shape should be in a chart at a calculated position. Not in a cell.

Comment: @Lvassilopoulos you are putting the shape inside a chart type sheet ?

Comment: Does anybody know how to fix this?